# Integrate multiple devices from Azure IoT Hub

Tags: azure, iot, thingsboard, hub

I followed the tutorial from your help site:
https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/integrations/azure-iot-hub/

It works well so far. However, I can only use one integration for a single device (as I can only add credentials for a single device per integration). I cannot find a way to add credentials for another device except for adding another integration (which is not intended, I guess). So this is what I tried: adding another integration. However, I can only add 20 integrations which amounts to 20 sensors. Am I supposed to add a new integration for each of my IoT Hub devices? Or is it possible to channel multiple devices through a single integration?

Thank you.

Best,
Andy

Comment: please share the details of what you tried for multiple devices

Comment: Sure. 

The exmple from the link allows me to add a single device from IoT Hub. I cannot find a way to add credentials for another device except for adding another integration (which is not intended, I guess).

So this is what I tried: adding another integration. However, I can only add 20 integrations which amouts to 20 sensors. However, I'd like to integrate hundreds. There schould be a way to do so?!

Comment: @ andir Schedule and broadcast jobs are used to update millions of devices. Use Azure IoT Hub to schedule and track jobs that update millions of devices.giving you same example  try with code with thingsborad

Answer (score 0):

Schedule and broadcast jobs is used for update millions of devices    . Use Azure IoT Hub to schedule and track jobs that update millions of devices.The below code is for Node.js to interact with Azure IoT Hub and schedule jobs for device methods and twin updates.

I followed [DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/schedule-jobs-node) scheduling and broadcasting jobs using Node.js with Azure IoT Hub.

**Code:**

```js
var methodParams = {
    methodName: 'lockDoor',
    payload: null,
    responseTimeoutInSeconds: 15
};

var methodJobId = uuid.v4();
console.log('scheduling Device Method job with id: ' + methodJobId);
jobClient.scheduleDeviceMethod(methodJobId,
                                queryCondition,
                                methodParams,
                                startTime,
                                maxExecutionTimeInSeconds,
                                function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Could not schedule device method job: ' + err.message);
    } else {
        monitorJob(methodJobId, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Could not monitor device method job: ' + err.message);
            } else {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
            }
        });
    }
});

var twinPatch = {
    etag: '*',
    properties: {
        desired: {
            building: '43',
            floor: 3
        }
    }
};
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Azure:**

[image]

**Updated:**

You can integrate more than one device by adjusting the **queryCondition** parameter. Here's how you can modify the **queryCondition** to target multiple devices:

```js
var deviceIds = ['deviceId1', 'deviceId2', 'deviceId3']; // Add the IDs of your devices here
var queryCondition = "deviceId IN ['" + deviceIds.join("', '") + "']";
```

Replace 'device1', 'device2', 'device3' with the IDs of the devices you want to target. You can list as many device IDs as needed, separated by commas inside the square brackets.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I might not get it, but I can't see the relation to my initial questions which asks: How do I integrate more than one device into ThingsBoard. Can you elaborate?

Comment: You can integrate more than one device by adjusting the **queryCondition** parameter. Here's how you can modify the **queryCondition** to target multiple devices:

```js
var queryCondition = "deviceId IN ['device1', 'device2', 'device3']";
```

Replace 'device1', 'device2', 'device3' with the IDs of the devices you want to target. You can list as many device IDs as needed, separated by commas inside the square brackets.